# Override DNS entry when VPN connected without DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, azure

I have moved a server into Azure, the server is working perfectly however now I want to connect users to the server when they're at home using a VPN.

I have setup the VPN in Azure and this is working correctly, I can access the server using the local IP address (10.0.X.X) however there are multiple applications that are setup to use the public DNS entry (xxxx.[region].cloudapp.azure.com).

All the machines connect to the internet via a router using googles public DNS (8.8.8.8) but obviously when using the VPN, this resolves to the public IP not the private IP address.

I know I can create a DNS server and use this instead of Googles however this seems like overkill for this single re-direction.

**Is there any way to redirect this single DNS entry when I connect to the VPN or via a batch script I can give to the users to use when they're at home?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friendly speaking it would be better to configure DNS according to "best practises".

But there is other way. I assume the endusers have Windows Client OS. Perform on each client (or with GPO/Automation):

1) Create a task in Windows Task scheduler

2) Set trigger to event 20267 (establishing VPN)

3) Set the following batch (modify IP and FQDN) as an action:

```
copy C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.bak /Y
echo "10.0.X.X  xxxx.[region].cloudapp.azure.com" >> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts 
ipconfig /flushdns
```

4) Create the second task in Windows Task scheduler

5) Set trigger to event 20268 (close VPN connection)

6) Set the following batch as an action to restore original configuration:

```
    copy C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.bak C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts /Y
    ipconfig /flushdns
```

Comment: This looks very promising!

Comment: Worked perfectly

Comment: You are welcome!